# Ellipse through defined points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to (approximate) an ellipse given three points, namely (20,20), (-40,0) and (0,-40). I know this ellipse is rotated by 45 degrees, so the mayor axis of the ellipse is 45 degrees rotated anti clockwise in comparison to the x axis, but I don't know the center of the ellipse.

Given this information I think it is impossible to determine the exact expression for the ellipse. And because I don't know the center of the ellipse I cannot use `\draw` or `\pgfpathellipse` commands. Nevertheless I think Tikz should be able to approximate an ellipse through these points?

Comment: You need five points to define an ellipse no?

Comment: If you rotate the points by –45 degrees, the ellipse would have equation `(x+h)^2/a^2+(y+k)^2/b^2=1` and you see that there is a condition missing.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is an underdetermined ellipse, just guess

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt](a) at (2,2) {};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt](b) at (-4,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt](c) at (0,-4) {};

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{20mm}{20mm}}
\pgfpatharcto{30.5mm}{60mm}{0}{1}{1}{ \pgfpoint{0mm}{-40mm} }
\pgfusepath{draw}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]